# Java project compiles with Maven but Eclipse still shows errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am new to Maven and an using it to build my Java project. I have two questions:

1. I was able to successfully compile my project with Maven but Eclipse still reports compile time errors. I know these errors are because I have not added external jars to Eclipse's build path, but is there any other way I can resolve these errors?
2. How do I run my Java project with Maven?

Here's my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.springhibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringHibernateAssignment</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>SpringHibernateAssignment</name>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groupId>com.springhibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>SpringHibernateAssignment</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <file>${basedir}/lib/ojdbc14.jar</file>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-install-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.4,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you please provide output of your maven compile and the output of the eclipse error.

Comment: If you're adding dependencies by hand, you're Doing It Wrong; that's what Maven is for.

Comment: Why are you changing the default folder structure? Does not make sense. Keep the default. One of the most important paradigms: Convention over configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The m2e plug in for Eclipse will integrate Maven so that Eclipse will automatically include JAR's from the local Maven cache based on the contents of the POM.xml.

And excluding all Java source files explains why Maven's build succeeds without any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Put the third party libraries as dependencies in your pom.xml.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxr-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

You can find them in [here](http://mvnrepository.com/).

Comment: Actually i already have all the jar files. I developed my project without using Maven first and now i want to convert it to Maven.
I am not able to figure out that how can i add multiple external jar files to the maven like we add external jars in java build path in normal java project.

Answer (score 0):

If those jars you mention are public frameworks, you should be able to find them in the maven central repository and add them to your project just like Eranda explained. If you have jars that cannot be found publicly, you have to add them first to your local maven repo using maven install-file plugin: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 0):

May be your M2_Home is not set, can you confirm. You may be building the project from the command line not from the eclipse ( Guess).

Suggestions:
 1. Set M2_HOME.
 2. Clean or Build the Project from eclipse, it will add all your dependent jars to references